# How can I track the download count of files in Easy Digital Downloads admin panel?

Tags: wordpress

I am using Easy Digital Downloads (EDD) plugin in WordPress to manage my digital products. I would like to have a way to track the download count for each file in the admin panel.

For example, I want to see how many times a specific file has been downloaded by customers. This will help me understand the popularity of my products and make informed decisions about my offerings.

I have checked the default settings and searched for plugins that could provide this functionality, but so far, I haven't found a straightforward solution within EDD.

Could someone please suggest a method or point me in the right direction on how to implement a download count feature for files in the Easy Digital Downloads admin panel? If there's any code snippet or plugin that can help achieve this, I would greatly appreciate your guidance!

Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights you can provide!

I have checked all the available options but nothing seems to work

Comment: You can create your own db table where to store your data. On click download button get the file find its ID based on that ID u can populate your new table with File ID Name Clicks etc you can even store it by user depends how you want to sort your data.